# nifi publishKafka processor can not publish on kafka 2.5

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to publish a simple json to a kafka topic. I'm using the dockerized version of both apache nifi and apache kafka (latest of both). the kafka version is 2.5 but there is no processor to connect to this version.

When I use the other publishKafka processors I get this error:"can not update metadata in 5000 ms".

Can anyone help me about the problem?

Comment: That error generally implies that the topic does not exist. Are you sure the topic exists?

Comment: thanks matthew. yes I created the topic before running the flow. Also I checked it in the topics list and it's available. Also I published some message manually on it

Comment: It could also be the Delivery Guarantee property in the Publish Kafka processor. Is it set to Best Effort? I do not believe it will work using a Docker instance if it is set otherwise.

Comment: I set the transaction to false and so it doesn't need the guarantee property now. Could the problem refer to this transaction?

Comment: Just to confirm, you are using PublishKafkaRecord_2_0, https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-0-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.PublishKafkaRecord_2_0/index.html

Comment: Actually I used PublishKafka_2_0 because I don't want each message as one record.

Comment: Note this has been crossposted on the Cloudera Community: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/nifi-publishKafka-processor-can-not-publish-on-kafka-2-5/m-p/298002#M218931 Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but for future readers: I expect Nifi to work well with 2.4 as that is the version Cloudera (a driving force behind Nifi and Kafka) is currently building against

Answer (score 0):

Kafka up to 2.6 is now supported in NiFi 1.12.X. You need to upgrade and switch to the new Kafka 2.6 processors.